# Regex to match the first letter in a word ONLY

Tags: c#, regex, linq

This SHOULD be simple for some reason I seem to be stretching the boundaries of my regex knowledge. I simply need a regex that will match the first letter in a word. I only want letters from an array that start with `x` `y` or `z`. This seems to reduce the amount of items in the array... but I'm not sure why since the results aren't what I'm expecting.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[x|y|z]");
string[] array = text.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToArray()); // 'text' is an array
```

Comment: Do you really need regex for this? Would be pretty easy to check the first letter in a string and check if its x y or z.

Comment: I'd like to know the regex that does this

Comment: You should not use `|` in character class since it means character `|` and not OR.... `[xyz]` is enough.

Comment: also is that typo here ?  `x.regex.IsMatch(x)` it should be `regex.IsMatch(x)`

Comment: Thank you, just typed the code instead of copy/paste

Comment: Why do you insist on a regex? What about [`string[] array = text.Where(x => x.StartsWith("x") || x.StartsWith("y") || x.StartsWith("z")).ToArray();`](http://ideone.com/5no3Cv)?

Comment: Seems like you were just looking for `^[xzy]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible here is what you are searching:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(x|y|z).+$");
```

Comment: @NealR also this pattern `^[xyz]` should work since you only want to check for the first character.

Comment: @NealR Glad to help you :)

Comment: Note that expression will only match the first word in each entry of the array text.  So assuming each entry in the array is a single word then if this works for you.  Also http://regexr.com/v1/ is a great resource for trying expressions

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\b([xyz]\w*)
```

`\w*` means zero to many word characters. When using `[]` the `|` is implied between the characters. So, `[xyz]` means x, y, or z. Then placing the `()` captures the word. So, in short we find something that is the start of a word then capture a string of word characters starting with x, y, or z.

Also, you can change `\w` with `[A-Za-z]` since some will include `_` and numbers as a word character:)

Can also go [here](https://regex101.com/) to test regex. Even though it is for *php*, *python*, and *javascript* it still is nice to test:)

Hope this helps some!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to do what you need:

```
new Regex(@"\b[x|y|z](?=\w*\b)")
```

Comment: That is the proper Regex expression I was trying to get in my earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your answer right, then you want to match words that start with any of the letters `x`, `y` or `z`. The answer you accepted would match everything after the occurence of `x` or `y` or `z`.

try this instead:

```
[xyz]\w+
```

in a text like

> lalalalla nananna x xaa yaaa zaaa lalala

it would match the three words

```
xaa 
yaaa 
zaaa
```

individually.

if you also want to match single occurences of the letters, use

```
[xyz]\w*
```

instead, which would match

```
x
xaa 
yaaa 
zaaa
```

.